# SSRS report streamed as image and printed doesnt match PDF export

Tags: c#, .net, reporting-services, webforms, console-application

We have a client that streams down SSRS reports into two applications, one a console and the second a WinForms applications. The console application automatically generates the latest report for the users and has the option to auto print the same report to the default selected printer. When exporting the report to PDF the report looks perfect but when the report is auto printed the text sizing seems to get scaled down slightly, the text spacing is reduced, and some of the placement varies compared to the Auto Generated PDF.

When a report is auto printed we stream down the report as an Image and then created a custom PrintPage method to create a rectangle and then set the image inside the rectangle and then send the image to print(see code below).

```
private void PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs ev)
    {

        var pageImage = new Metafile(_mStreams[_currentPageIndex]);

        // Adjust rectangular area with printer margins.
        var adjustedRect = new Rectangle(
            ev.PageBounds.Left - (int)ev.PageSettings.HardMarginX,
            ev.PageBounds.Top - (int)ev.PageSettings.HardMarginY,
            ev.PageBounds.Width,
            ev.PageBounds.Height);

        // Draw a white background for the report
        ev.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, adjustedRect);

        // Draw the report content
        ev.Graphics.DrawImage(pageImage, adjustedRect);

        // Prepare for the next page. Make sure we haven't hit the end.
        _currentPageIndex++;
        ev.HasMorePages = (_currentPageIndex < _mStreams.Count);

    }
```

The margins and sizing of the page match up when the process is completed but clearly there are differences in how the text is displayed on the auto printed copy. Below are screen shots of the two reports where you can see the spacing and placement of some of the text varies a bit from the auto generated PDF report. This issue effects the reports more when its larger 50+ page documents where the Auto Generated PDF contains a few more pages than the Image export.

#### Auto Generated Screen Shot

[image: Auto Generated Screen Shot]

#### Auto Printed Screen Shot

[image: Auto Printed Screen Shot]

Any help with this is greatly appreciated, Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I got it back working by scraping the old printing functionality in favor of using Adobe to auto print the recently generated report. The crux of my issue pertained to re-exporting the report as an Image from SSRS. This caused all the formatting and styles to get adjusted to match that format.